# AddClass works in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this kind of jQuery:

```
var currentPageName = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

$("div#navigation-container nav.main-navigation ul li a").each(function () {
  var link = $(this).attr("href");

  if (link.contains(currentPageName)) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).css("color", "white");
  }
})'
```

It gets current url and ad to navigation some active css class, it is working ok in Firefox, but in Chrome, i can not get it work?
Any solutions?

Comment: It is working ok in mozzila, i think problem is with document.location?

Comment: Chrome does not support `String.prototype.contains`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains - Firefox has supported it since version 18. Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not support [String.prototype.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) - Firefox has supported it since version 18. Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead:

```
if (link.indexOf(currentPageName) > -1) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).css("color", "white");
}
```